# Ударение в слове глядя

Tags: ударение

В словарях допускается двойная норма : гл**я**дя и гляд**я**. В каких случаях, по вашему мнению, можно употребить второй вариант?

Людмила, спасибо за прекрасный ответ!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Русская грамматика Академии наук допускает колебания ударения: глЯдя и (доп.) глядЯ: не глЯдя в книгу, не глядЯ в книгу; шёл, глЯдя по сторонам и глядЯ по сторонам; в составе предложного сочетания = наречному (глядя на что-н. и по чему-н.) – только глЯдя : когда?-на ночь глЯдя пошли; поступайте как?- глЯдя по обстоятельствам. Но в старой грамматике предпочтителен был как раз вариант глядЯ- это точно деепричастие, а глЯдя - вносил что-то переносное от наречия, он употреблялся в связанном виде, во фразеологизмах. ГлЯдя на ночь - мы на неё не глядим, смысл переносный.ГлЯдя на обстоятельства - мы на них не глядим в прямом смысле.А вот глядЯ в одну точку - мы глядим в одну точку.Ударение не на основе, как и в остальных формах глагола: гляжУ, глядИшь, глядИт, глядЯт, глядЯ.

Answer (score 3):

В "Новом орфоэпическом словаре русского языка" Т.Ф. Ивановой (2008)ударение в деепричастии глЯдя указано только над первым слогом, без вариантов. Убеждена, что в современном русском языке это норма. Этот вариант ударения уверенно доминирует, а вариант глядЯ уходит в прошлое.

Comment: Не спорю, русское ударение изменчиво, возможно, глЯдя станет единственной нормой, ведь уже сейчас у глядЯ помета - доп., т.е. разговорное.Речь часто преобладает над языком, а говорят в большинстве случаев глЯдя, видимо, ориентируясь на те же афоризмы. Мы же не задумываемся, какая это часть речи и как произносить, а так более удобно и благозвучно.